# HTML tag debugging issue

Tags: html

Ok, so I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<h3>This is a heading</h> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a `<body>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is a heading</h1>
        <h2>This is a heading</h2>
        <h3>This is a heading</h3> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, the h3 closing tag has a typo, which I fixed.  It should be `</h3>`, but you had `</h>`.  Finally, if this is an html or xhtml document, it needs a doctype declaration.  I've added one of those as well - XHTML strict.  There are several possible doctypes; you'll have to pick the one that fits your situation.  That's getting a little beyond what you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

To find syntax errors, use the [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org) first. You will see that the only error is that the end tag for `h3` has been mistyped as `</h>` instead of the correct `</h3>`. For technical reasons, the error is reported in two error messages.

For practical reasons, you should add a document type declaration, such as `<!doctype html>`, at the very start of the document, to avoid [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html).

The use of tags like `<body>` and `</head>` is optional, except in XHTML, which has its own rules. Using such tags is a matter of taste and coding style, not correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters you don't have a body...

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <h2>This is a heading</h2>
    <h3>This is a heading</h3> 
</body>
</html>
```